# docker private registry change from v1 to v2 while pulling an image

Tags: docker, docker-registry

There is a docker is registry v2.
An image is pushed to docker private registry. Able to see it using `curl` command:

```
$ curl -s -X GET http://<registry>:<port>/v2/<image>/tags/list
{"name":"<image>","tags":["latest"]}
```

However, not able to pull the image from other machines. It appears that it is trying to **pull from v1 instead of v2**

Pulling the above image on a windows 10 machine.

```
docker pull <registry>:<port>/<image>:latest
```

*Getting the following error:*

> Pulling repository <registry>:<port>/<image>
>   Network timed out while trying to connect to
>   http://<registry>:<port>/**v1**/repositories/<image>/images.
>   You may want to check your internet connection or if you are behind a proxy.

Not using any proxy settings.

Here is version details

```
Client:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   c6d412e
 Built:        Tue Mar 28 00:40:02 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   c6d412e
 Built:        Fri Mar 24 00:00:50 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

Could not found any `docker settings` for changing from v1 to v2.

How do I make it to pull from v2 / resolve the above error?

**EDIT:** log shows

> ICMP Destination Unreachable: Destination port unreachable

Comment: V1 is probably used as fallback after V2 failed. Your problem is probably not that V1 is used but that there is an issue that prevents V2 from succeeding.  try docker logs -f 'registryContainer' if the registry shows nothing in its logs it is clearly a connectivity issue